# Touchpad sensitivity way too high on lowest setting (ZenbookPrime UX32VD-DH71) 12.04LTS

Tags: 12.04, touchpad

I have followed the guide https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AsusZenbookPrime here and I am having multiple issues with my touchpad.

1) The sensitivity is far too high even when on the lowest setting in the settings option. Is there a commandline way to reduce it further?

2) The area of the touchpad that is registered as a right-click is only at the very bottom of the touchpad and so most of my right-clicks are registered as left-clicks. How can I make the right-click area be taller?

I have an Elantech touchpad. I set up the clickpad.sh as described, removing the inverse scrolling because I am not a fan of that:

```
#!/bin/bash 
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad disable-while-typing false  
xinput set-prop "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad" "Synaptics ClickPad" 1 
xinput set-prop "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad" "Synaptics Soft Button Areas" 1956 0 1737 0 1304 1955 1737 0 
syndaemon -i 1.7 -d -t -K
xinput set-prop "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad" "Synaptics Scrolling Distance" 35, 35 # scroll more responsive
xinput set-prop "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad" "Synaptics Finger" 1, 15, 50 # ups click sensitivity, values '1, 15, 255' disable trackstick emulation
xinput set-prop "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad" "Synaptics Tap FastTap" 1 # faster taps
```

Answer (score 0):

On my Thinkpad, *increasing* rather than decreasing "Synaptics Scrolling distance" value slowed my two-finger scroll speed.

Comment: Are you sure you're answering the question here? You seem to assume the problem in the OP is about scrolling, but I see no indication for that. I read it is an issue with regular sensitivity/speed. And of course, the setting about scrolling distance is the distance your fingers need to move to hit a scroll event; hence increasing that value lowers the overall scroll speed.

Comment: Yes, my answer applies only to scrolling: the value 35, 35 in the answer is way lower than mine, so I assumed it should have made the scrolling extremely sensitive.